# Need to retrieve errored email addresses that we have attempted to import via API

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, import

I run the marketing side (not the code side) of ET for our company and periodically manually import lists of users into our ET account. When I do, I always receive an error report telling me what email addresses - if any - could not be imported and why.

I need to see a similar list for the errored email addresses that our API sends to ET to import.  Basically, I would like to know ALL the email addresses that we have attempted to import via the API, but who have been rejected for any reason, from July 2013 (when we started using ET) through now.  I'd also like to see the reasons WHY they have been rejected, if possible.

I am NOT a developer so I cannot implement code, and wouldn't even know how.  Our development team is too busy to deal with this.  So, I need someone at ET to pull this info for us.  The folks over at ET customer support said they can't do it, and told me that I should ask you guys.

So - help??

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your account manager, and get pricing for a custom data extract.  This would be developed, and dropped in your account for you to run as needed.